# "Access Not Configured" error in YouTubeDataAPI

Tags: api, youtube, get, youtube-data-api

I am integrating one website with youtube channel own. I needed to use the YouTube Data API. Google provides a specific URL to use the GET method in order to get data.
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` `(I used my API here)`
When I use it, I got an error with the code 403 and reason accessNotConfigured.
" "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in a project before or it is disabled."

YouTube Data API is enabled in my project. I don't understand where is an error and how can I solve/configure it

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the [*mine*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) parameter should only be used upon a proper authorization flow.

Also note that a query to the API's [Channels endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) needs to be getting the [*id*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) of the channel you're interested in.